# How to make a Form Input Field Large?

Tags: html, css

For the form below, how could I make the input field big, like maybe 100 pixels in height by 400 pixels in length?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
<form action="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/comments2.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">  

    <div class="addacomment"><label for="title">Add a comment:</label></div> 
    <div class="submissionfield"><input name="title" type="title" id="title" maxlength="1000"></div>  

    <div class="submissionbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can avoid using the div by applying the class in the `<input>` itself

your CSS can be

```
.submissionfield { width: 90px; height: 390px; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 30):

Any reason not to use a TEXTAREA form element instead?

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="TITLE">
</textarea>
```

Comment: i think this would give you trouble during cross-browser testing

Comment: @pixeltocode Which browser doesn't support `textarea`? `textarea` has been a part of html since the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

You can add css to the input, like:

```
.input-element{
font-size: 100px; // for say a select
width: 400px;
}
```

or you can add height but you might have to add !important to it...

```
.input-element{
height: 100px !important;
width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp) ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea)) field?

Answer (score 1):

for better n bigger input field textarea is effective.

```
<textarea type="text"
name="pre_book_sugg"
class="form-control"
style="height: calc(2.5em + 4.75rem + 2px);"
```

>

//input value

Comment: more description please

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the font-size in the css.
This will make the input boxes bigger, and allow for more readable text.

*Chrome*

CSS

```
form input{
    font-size: 2em;
}
```